# Docker automated build not showing Dockerfile after completion

Tags: github, docker

I setup some automated builds in github and the Dockerfile tab is showing empty for some reason.  The builds are successful and I can see the dockerfile contents in the build details, but for some reason its not populating the Dockerfile tab.  Am I missing a step somewhere?

Comment: I can definitely say that you're  missing something. What? Only God (just choose any God) in his/her/it almigthy will know, as you're not sharing any information. [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Just doing the standard auto build method.  I have a single repo in github (jusrob/docker-nzbget) is one.  And an automated build (jusrob/nzbget) that points to that repo.  Everything is default settings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my own problem.  In the build settings it by default is creating two entries under monitored repositories, one for the master branch and a blank one.  Delete the entry for the blank one and all is well.